# How can I calculate the maximum load of a steel box section frame?

Tags: steel, deflection

Is it possible to calculate the maximum load of the steel structure shown in the image using its dimensions?
[image: steel frame]

[image: views]

Comment: So which is it? Is it possible? Or just want it done for you?

Comment: If it is possible then I am looking for the answer or any info on how to calculate it

Comment: This isn't the right place to just ask for "the answer" - and even if someone gave you a number that they claimed was "the answer", you won't know if it is right, and *you* will have to take the blame (and the claim for damages!) if they were wrong and the structure fails!

Comment: " any info on how to calculate it" - if it is important to you, find a properly qualified professional engineer, and pay them to do the work. We can't teach you the contents of a Mech Eng degree here!

Comment: @alephzero suggestion - how about you stop trying to criticise a perfectly valid question. I obviously wouldn't take any answer and run with it. My question was simply "is it possible" which is perfectly ok to ask. Then if it was possible the next obvious question was going to be "how". Not everyone on here is going to be a pro at asking questions like you apparently are, so if you don't have anything helpful to say then how about don't say anything? Just be mindful of the fact that some people asking q's may have little knowledge of the topic, so try to be helpful rather than criticise.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Some of the other pieces of information needed are divided in two parts: material and structural properties of your support; and load characteristics.

Material: What alloy or steel and what specific structural properties, and section properties such as whether they are hollow sections or solid, how they are put together, what weld type or spot-welding.

Load characteristics: whether loads are permeant or temporary, if they are lowered to this support gently or if they will be dropped. If they will be Yanked away or lifted. If they are solid or liquid, or a machine? this support is anchored to the ground or just sitting, or will be moveable.

So there is some parameters to consider before one can estimate the adequacy of strength of this support.

Comment: So really Yes possible with the required information...

Comment: @SolarMike or "really yes, if you first change the question into one that has an answer" ;)

Comment: @alephzero **many** questions on here start with no possible answer, until further information is supplied...